# Ubuntu freeze at any moment

Tags: freeze

my pc (dell inspiron 15) on which ubuntu is installed frequently freezes, here is the logs before the last freeze in attachments.
I hope you will see what is the problem because I have no idea.

[image: log before image 2]

[image: logs just before freeze]

Comment: freezing can be very difficult to debug and can be from anything from failing hardware to faulty ram to video drivers or even wirelss drivers. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash

Comment: definitely the c-state bug (see your device listed in the answer)

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, actually the problem solved itself after few updates of the software library!